# parsing xml with vbscript

Tags: xml, asp-classic, vbscript, xml-parsing

Anyone have any examples of parsing xml with vbscript?  I have a .NET generic list serialized into XML that I'm sending to a classic asp page. I thought I'd be able to use XMLDom, but the libraries don't seem to be installed on the server, so I'm looking for another solution.  (Was getting "Object Required: documentElement" error)

Basically I'm passing a list of around 15 objects in the form of an xml string that contains a headline and a main article section, and I want to loop through the list and print out both.

This was what I had before I found out XMLDom wasn't installed:

```
set xmlDoc=CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
xmlDoc.async="false"
xmlDoc.loadXML(item)

Set objFirstChild = xmlDoc.documentElement.firstChild
Set objAttributes = objFirstChild.attributes
For Each Attr in objAttributes
   Response.write(Attr.Headline & "<br>")
   Response.write(Attr.Content & "<br>")
Next
Response.End
```

Any help appreciated - my VBScript is pretty rusty these days!

**EDIT** - Tried as well with `MSXML2.DOMDocument` but ended up with a Object Required error.

UPDATE - Sample XML included at request of @ulluoink:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<articles>
  <article>
    <newsID>7</newsID>
    <headline>This is headline 1</headline>
    <content><![CDATA[<p>This is the start of the main content of the article</p><p>This is the next paragraph.</p> ]]></content>
    <date>04/06/2013 00:00</date>
  </article>
  <article>
    <newsID>7</newsID>
    <headline>This is headline 2</headline>
    <content><![CDATA[<p>This is the start of the main content of the article</p><p>This is the next paragraph.</p> ]]></content>
    <date>04/06/2013 00:00</date>
  </article>
  <article>
    <newsID>7</newsID>
    <headline>This is headline 3</headline>
    <content><![CDATA[<p>This is the start of the main content of the article</p><p>This is the next paragraph.</p> ]]></content>
    <date>04/06/2013 00:00</date>
  </article>
</articles>
```

Comment: if xmldom "was not installed" you would get the error at the line where you createobject("...")

Comment: E-on, now it's hard to find out server without pre-installed XML, ulluoink right. Please checkout Your code. In our (in company) ASPClassic scripts we are using statement like this `Set xmlDoc = Server.CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.3.0")`. Please specify exact string number, where error raised. If it's a not string, with `Server.CreateObject`, try check `xmlDoc.parseError` property and watch on returned object.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK attribute objects don't have a property `Headline` or `Content`. Are you trying to write the values of the attributes `Headline` and `Content` of the child node? For that you need something like this:

```
For Each attr In objAttributes
  If attr.Name = "Headline" Or attr.Name = "Content" Then
    response.write attr.Value & "<br>"
  End If
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

In general, you shouldn't use DOM methods without error/plausibility checks. A minimalistic skeleton for starting with XML 'parsing' applied to your input:

```
  Dim sFSpec : sFSpec    = resolvePath( "..\data\17014567.xml" )
  Dim oXDoc  : Set oXDoc = CreateObject( "Msxml2.DOMDocument" )
  oXDoc.setProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"
  oXDoc.async = False
  oXDoc.load sFSpec

  If 0 = oXDoc.ParseError Then
     WScript.Echo sFSpec, "looks ok"
     ' ? Set objFirstChild = xmlDoc.documentElement.firstChild
     Dim X : Set X = oXDoc.documentElement.firstChild
     WScript.Echo 0, TypeName(X), X.tagName
     ' ? Set objAttributes = objFirstChild.attributes
     Set X = X.attributes
     WScript.Echo 1, TypeName(X), X.length
     If 0 < X.length Then
        Dim Attr
        For Each Attr in X
            ' ? Attr.Headline, Attr.Content
        Next
     Else
        WScript.Echo 2, "no attributes!"
     End If
  Else
     WScript.Echo oXDoc.ParseError.Reason
  End If
```

output:

```
E:\trials\SoTrials\answers\8194209\data\17014567.xml looks ok
0 IXMLDOMElement article
1 IXMLDOMNamedNodeMap 0
2 no attributes!
```

clearly show, that there aren't any attributes to loop over.